# Can't get response body to log it in application insights

Tags: c#, .net-core, middleware, azure-application-insights

In order to log the `response body` into app-insights from `HttpContext` I should develop a `Middleware`, that intercepts each request and response and extracts the `HttpContext`, in my case `Response.Body` and then sends it into app-insights using `telemetryClient.TrackTrace()`.

The problem is that when I debug and extract the body of the respone is always empty.

This is my `Middleware` class

```
public class ResponseBodyInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseBodyInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string resBody = await GetResponseBodyForTelemetry(context);
        SendDataToTelemetryLog(resBody, context);

    }

    private static void SendDataToTelemetryLog(string respBody, HttpContext context)
    {
       if (context.Request.Method == "POST" || context.Request.Method =="PUT")
       {
                var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
                var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry
                {
                    Message = respBody,
                    SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Information
                };
                //Send a trace message for display in Diagnostic Search. 
                telemetryClient.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
        }
     }

    private async Task<string> GetResponseBodyForTelemetry(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
               context.Response.Body = memStream;

               //await the responsebody
                 await _next(context);
                 if (context.Response.StatusCode == 204)
                 {
                     return null;
                 }

                 memStream.Position = 0;
                 var responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                 memStream.Position = 0;
                 await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);

                 return responseBody;
             }
         }
         finally
         {
             context.Response.Body = originalBody;
         }
     }
}
```

`StartUp.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
            app.UseDefaultFiles()
                .UseStaticFiles()
                .UseMiddleware<ResponseBodyInitializer>()
                .UseBotFramework();

}
```

OR is there any other way to log the response in app-insights?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which you have to do it:-

1)  You have to implement ITelemetryInitializer.

2)  Inject the IHttpContextAccessor to the class and read the response stream within the Initialize method.

3) Ensure the passed ITelemetry object is from type RequestTelemetry and that the HttpRequest was either a Post or Put.

4)  Then you can read the response using the IHttpContext.HttpContext.Response.Body property and log it using Application Insight.

Finally, register your class within the ConfigureService method in your Startup.cs

I see, you are not implementing ITelemetryInitializer ,also read the stream in Initialize method

Try these steps and see if it helps.

Comment: I've tried this way but I am getting the error "stream is not readable".The thing is that when you use the initializer you don't have a response yet so you'll have to await that somehow. And I am not able to inject the the `RequestDelegate` to await the context. Your way is ideal to read the `HttpContext.Request`, that works perfectly for me.